# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JC one Date' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I am trying to insert into a new table with an extra column that converts 1 to 'JC one date', 2 to 'JC two date and so on until 'JC ten Date'

If I run the query as a select it works fine, if I try to insert into the table I get:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JC one Date' to data type int.

If I restrict all the `When` clauses to just the first on, its fine, but with all the `When` clauses in, its erroring.

The code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BRIDGE_PrePivot_Output]
    SELECT 
        [Employee Number],
        [Cumulative],
        CASE 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 1 THEN 'JC one Date'
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 2 THEN 'JC two Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 3 THEN 'JC three Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 4 THEN 'JC four Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 5 THEN 'JC five Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 6 THEN 'JC six Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 7 THEN 'JC seven Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 8 THEN 'JC eight Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 9 THEN 'JC nine Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 10 THEN 'JC ten Date' 
        END AS [Which Date],
        [JC Date],
        [JC Occupational Area],
        [JC level of Seniority]
    FROM 
        dbo.[BRIDGE_JOBCHA_CUMUL] 
    GROUP BY 
        [Employee Number],
        CASE 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 1 THEN 'JC one Date'
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 2 THEN 'JC two Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 3 THEN 'JC three Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 4 THEN 'JC four Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 5 THEN 'JC five Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 6 THEN 'JC six Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 7 THEN 'JC seven Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 8 THEN 'JC eight Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 9 THEN 'JC nine Date' 
            WHEN [Cumulative] = 10 THEN 'JC ten Date' 
        END AS [Which Date],
        [Cumulative], [JC Date],
        [JC Occupational Area], [JC level of Seniority]
    ORDER BY
        [Employee Number]
```

Comment: I would **strongly recommend** always explicitly specifying which columns you're inserting into - `INSERT INTO [dbo].[BRIDGE_PrePivot_Output] (col1, col2, ......, colN) .....`

Comment: You can't alias an expression in the `GROUP BY`; I would expect the above to generate a syntax error before it generates a conversion error. It, however, makes little sense to use a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation. If you don't want multiple rows with the same values, then use a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: As for the error, I suspect the problem is the related to what @marc_s suggests. As you have omitted the column list in the `INSERT` clause you are probably not inserting the values into the columns you *think* you are. Columns aren't `INSERT`ed into a table based on their aliases, but based on their ordinal positions. When you omit the columns in the `INSERT` clause then it is *assumed* you are `INSERT`ing values into *every* column in the order of their ordinal positions in the table.

Comment: It may be something im doing, but the DISTINCT was bringing in DISTINCTs for me, as that was my first action. I dont get any error if I just run from the SELECT query. The insert into is the pain.

Comment: @OneDevilsSt: that's exactly what I was trying to convey - most likely, the order in which your `SELECT` returns the columns doesn't match the columns of the table you're inserting into, resulting a datatype clash. If you **explicitly define** which columns you insert into, you can **control** which columns those are and make sure to insert the right data into the right columns

Comment: Is your third column in your table `BRIDGE_PrePivot_Output` a `VARCHAR`?